# How to make Radio button behave like checkbox?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working in "native-base": "3.3.7", and I am trying to make the radio button behave like a checkbox but the selection process should be the same as the radio button means if I click on the radio button then it checked and if I click again on the same then it should be unchecked.

here is my code snippet

```
 <Radio.Group
    name="exampleGroup"
    accessibilityLabel="CONSTANTS.QUESTION_1"
    defaultValue=""
    value={this.state.performanceRadioGroup}
    onChange={this.accademicQuestionsOnPerformance}
>
    <Radio
        _text={{
            mx: 2,
        }}
        my="2"
        colorScheme="purple"
        style={{ borderColor: '#813588' }}
        value="veryGoodRadio"
        icon={
            <Icon
                style={{ color: '#813588' }}
                as={
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="circle" />
                }
            />
        }
    >
        Very Good
    </Radio>

    <Radio
        _text={{
            mx: 2,
        }}
        colorScheme="purple"
        my="2"
        style={{ borderColor: '#813588' }}
        value="goodRadio"
        icon={
            <Icon
                style={{ color: '#813588' }}
                as={
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="circle" />
                }
            />
        }
    >
        Good
    </Radio>

    <Radio
        _text={{
            mx: 2,
        }}
        colorScheme="purple"
        my="2"
        style={{ borderColor: '#813588' }}
        value="needImpRadio"
        icon={
            <Icon
                style={{ color: '#813588' }}
                as={
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="circle" />
                }
            />
        }
    >
        Needs Improvement
    </Radio>
</Radio

 accademicQuestionsOnPerformance = async (e: any) => {
    let good = false;
    let veryGood = false;
    let needImprovement = false;
    if (e === 'veryGoodRadio') {
        veryGood = !this.state.veryGoodRadio;
        this.setState({ performanceRadioGroup: 'veryGoodRadio' });
    } else if (e === 'goodRadio') {
        this.setState({ performanceRadioGroup: 'goodRadio' });
        good = !this.state.goodRadio;
    } else {
        this.setState({ performanceRadioGroup: 'needImpRadio' });
        needImprovement = !this.state.needImpRadio;
    }
    await this.setState({
        veryGoodRadio: veryGood,
        goodRadio: good,
        needImpRadio: needImprovement,
    });
};
```

I want only one radio button selected as radio buttons have properties but it should unchecked also like checkbox

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the working example in expo snack?

Comment: Your intention is to have radio group with no default value? And once selection is made to be able to clear selection to null?

Comment: Correct @ЕмилЦоков but problem is that in Native base V2 had some properties which is not in V3. like onPress